# Change text font using menu

Tags: java, swing, fonts, awt, jmenuitem

I have this code that when user click on one of the fonts "bold or italic..." the text should change. I couldn't add the action listener that will do that:

```
import java.awt.*;
import javax.swing.*;
import java.awt.event.*;

public class question4 extends JFrame {

    private JTextField textField;
    private JComboBox fontbox;
    private String names[]={ "Bold","Italic","Plain"};
    private Icon icons[]={};


    public question4()
    {
        super("JcheckBox");
        setLayout(new FlowLayout());//set frame
        fontbox = new JComboBox(names);//set jcobobox
        fontbox.setMaximumRowCount(3);
        //listener

        add(fontbox);
        //add the text content
        textField = new JTextField ("Hello World", 20);
        textField.setFont(new Font("Calibri", Font.BOLD,18));//set the text font and size
        add(textField);//add textfield to jframe
    }

    public static void main(String args[])
    {
        question4 obj = new question4();//create object
        obj.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        obj.setSize(700,400);
        obj.setVisible(true);
    }//end main

 }//end class
```

Comment: What did you try? What are you having trouble with?

Comment: Please indent your code correctly.

Comment: Start by reading how to add a [menu](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/menu.html) to a JFrame. If you are having problems with that then ask and we will help.

Comment: *"any help plz"*  Please spell words properly.

Comment: @AndrewThompson sorry but this not a english class am here to ask about java no need to give correct spelling.

Comment: @SLaks thank you for stepping by someone had already helped

Comment: *"ask about java"*  My bad.  I thought you wanted to ask about Java ***&*** get an answer from members of a global audience.

Comment: @SumaiaSultan since not every one is a native speaker, and since we're all dealing with random strangers from the Internet observing correct spelling is not just pedantry. It is good manners. It is also vital to keeping questions, answers and comments clear and understandable. How is anyone supposed to help you if they cannot make heads or tails of your question simply because of poor spelling or grammar?

Comment: @AndrewThompson sorry.i am just a beginner.hope you accept my apology.

Comment: We were all new once, you are learning, no problem. :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to add `ActionListner` to `FontBox (JcomboBox)` Like this:

```
  private void fontboxActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {
    String font = (String) fontbox.getSelectedItem();

    if(font=="Bold")
        textField.setFont(new Font("Calibri", Font.BOLD, 18));
    else if(font == "Italic")
        textField.setFont(new Font("Calibri", Font.ITALIC, 18));
    else if(font == "Plain")
        textField.setFont(new Font("Calibri", Font.PLAIN, 18));

}
```

And call this method in your code like this:

```
fontbox.addActionListener(new java.awt.event.ActionListener() {
    public void actionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {
        fontboxActionPerformed(evt);
    }
});
```

Answer (score 3):

Rather than give you the solution outright, here are some guidelines to help you:

- Revisit the notion of an `ActionListener` (or even an [Action](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/misc/action.html)), specifically add one to the `JComboBox` `fontbox`.
- Create a `JComboBox` custom object for your `Font` styles so as to wrap both the text displayed and the integer constant to be used (hint). As a guide, see this [example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8804674/jtable-jcombobox-using-custom-objects)
- Then in your `ActionListener`, read the value returned from [getSelectedItem](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/JComboBox.html#getSelectedItem%28%29) and call `JTextField.setFont` accordingly using the style constant from the object.